# Native query does not seem to see hql query db changes

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a repository:

```
@Repository
public interface FirstRepository extends JpaRepository<Tab1, Long> {
```

Then I have another repository where I defined an update native query:

```
@Repository
public interface SecondRepository extends JpaRepository<Tab1, Long> {

  @Modifying
  @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = 
        "update Tab1 set something='A' where col1=:par")
 int performUpdate(@Param("par") Long par);
```

Then I have a service, and a method marked as @Transactional where I do:

```
@Service
public class Service{

@Transactional
public void method(){

     tab1.setValue(4);

     //changing the db status, still not committing
     repo1.save(tab1);

     //updating based on the value just set by tab1
     repo2.performUpdate(4);
}
```

For some reason the performUpdate method fails! It seems to not be able to see the changes performed by the repo1. Is it maybe because the first one is jpa while the other is a native query?

Comment: use `saveAndFlush` instead of `save`

Answer (score 2):

Solved thanks to Jens 's answer: I had to saveAndFlush instead of save: my changes were not seen by the second query.